# Concerning the word "provided"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I just find the word "provided" can be used as a conjunction. Here is an example:

> Cutting corners was acceptable, provided that you could get away with it.

Does this mean I can't say a sentence like the following one?

> Based on the information provided, we can draw a conclusion that ...

Does the above sentence mislead readers?

Comment: I don't understand the basis of your hunch that if your first example (*Cutting corners ...*) is valid, your second example (*Based on ...*) isn't. Can you please explain?

Comment: I was a little worried about the usage of the word "provided" in the second example may be wrong and understood by readers as the meaning from the first example. They won't, will they?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cambridge English Dictionary

'Provided that' is a conjunction meaning 'so long as' or 'on the condition that': 'so long as you could get away with it'.
'Provided' is also used in this way with the omitted word 'that' being understood by the reader or listener.
It always comes at the start of a phrase when used as a conjunction.

'Provided' is the past participle of the verb to provide meaning 'given' or 'submitted' which in this case coming immediately after a noun is used as a shortened form of the phrase 'which has been provided': 'Based on the information (which has been) provided, ...'
It always comes immediately after a noun when used like this.